# Chaining ENUM on Visual Basic 6

Tags: visual-studio, enums, vb6

Is it possible to chain ENUM on visual basic 6.0 ?

```
Enum RandomEnum

    WeekA = 100
    WeekB = 200

    Enum WeekC
        Day1 = 300
        Day2 = 400
    End Enum

End Enum
```

Does not seem to work ..

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing in VB 6.0. The closest alternative would be

```
Enum RandomEnum

    WeekA = 100
    WeekB = 200

    WeekC_Day1 = 300
    WeekC_Day2 = 400

End Enum
```

Comment: +1. For completeness here is a link to the MSDN VB6 documentation on the [`Enum` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243358(v=vs.60).aspx)